# Does the Ticket to Ride Africa version use tunneling?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-the-heart-of-africa

Does *Ticket to Ride: The Heart of Africa* use tunneling? *Ticket to Ride: Europe* does, but the original *Ticket to Ride* does not.

Answer (score 8):

**No, it does not.**

You can find the complete rules [here](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_africa_rules_2015.pdf). It does not make any mention of tunneling as part of claiming routes.

Here is a picture of the map; you can see that no routes look like the tunnels from Europe.

[image]